# SQL Select Where

Tags: sql, database

i have a table like this

```
UserFriends
Id        UserId        RequestId       Status
1         1             2               1
2         1             3               1
3         1             4               0
4         3             2               1
5         3             4               1
```

basically the structure is if status is 0 request not accepted else 1 accepted and they are friends

i am trying to do get user 2 friends how can i do ?

IMPORTANT EDIT:
i am trying to get user 3's friends. you know if user 1 added user 3 they are friends and user 3 added 2 and 4 they friends too (user 3 friends must return 1, 2 and 4 this is basic explanation)

Comment: Is `RequestId` the `UserId` of the user who made the request? Because if so, he already has two friends (`Id = 1` and `Id = 4`)

Comment: my problem is here user 1 added user 2 and status 1 in first row but i dont wanna add again this record like user 2 added user 1 and status 1

Comment: user ıd made request to requestid

Comment: You can do some kind of case statement where you get whichever of `UserId` and `RequestId` isn't user 2. But I'd rather just have a table with `UserId` and `Friends`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I read correctly, a friendship is characterized by either a user inviting another user or by that user being invited by other users, and in both cases the request was accepted.  If so, then the following `UNION` query should give the expected results:

```
SELECT RequestId
FROM UserFriends
WHERE UserId = 3 AND Status = 1
UNION
SELECT UserId
FROM UserFriends
WHERE RequestId = 3 AND Status = 1
```

I use a `UNION` here because a given user could appear as a friend more than once if a pair of users invited each other, or if an invitation were sent more than once.  I am assuming that you don't want to report the same user as a friend more than once.

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: i did it like this maybe one minute ago :). Anyway this is correct answer thank u for your effort and time :)